# reduce in performance when used multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am new to multi-threading and I have to write a program using multiple threads to increase its efficiency. At my first attempt what I wrote produced just opposite results. Here is what I have written:

```
class ThreadImpl implements Callable<ArrayList<Integer>> { 
    //Bloom filter instance for one of the table
    BloomFilter<Integer> bloomFilterInstance = null;
    // Data member for complete data access.
    ArrayList< ArrayList<UserBean> > data = null;
    // Store the result of the testing 
    ArrayList<Integer> result = null;
    int tableNo;

    public ThreadImpl(BloomFilter<Integer> bloomFilterInstance, 
                        ArrayList< ArrayList<UserBean> > data, int tableNo) {
        this.bloomFilterInstance = bloomFilterInstance;
        this.data = data;
        result  = new ArrayList<Integer>(this.data.size());
        this.tableNo = tableNo;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> call() {
        int[] tempResult = new int[this.data.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<data.size() ;++i) {
            tempResult[i] = 0;
        }
        ArrayList<UserBean> chkDataSet = null;
        for(int i=0; i<this.data.size(); ++i) {
            if(i==tableNo) {
                //do nothing;
            } else {
                chkDataSet = new ArrayList<UserBean> (data.get(i));
                for(UserBean toChk: chkDataSet) {
                    if(bloomFilterInstance.contains(toChk.getUserId())) {
                        ++tempResult[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            this.result.add(new Integer(tempResult[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the above class there are two data members `data` and `bloomFilterInstance` and they(the references) are passed from the main program. So actually there is only one instance of data and bloomFilterInstance and all the threads are accessing it simultaneously.

The class that launches the thread is(few irrelevant details have been left out, so all variables etc. you can assume them to be declared):

```
class MultithreadedVrsion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 1) {
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfTables);
            List<Callable<ArrayList<Integer>>> threadedBloom = new ArrayList<Callable<ArrayList<Integer>>>(noOfTables);
            for (int i=0; i<noOfTables; ++i) {
                threadedBloom.add(new ThreadImpl(eval.bloomFilter.get(i), 
                                                eval.data, i)); 
            }
            try {
                List<Future<ArrayList<Integer>>> answers = es.invokeAll(threadedBloom);
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("using more than one thread for bloom filters: " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
                System.out.println("**Printing the results**");
                for(Future<ArrayList<Integer>> element: answers) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> arrInt = element.get();
                    for(Integer i: arrInt) {
                        System.out.print(i.intValue());
                        System.out.print("\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did the profiling with jprofiler and

![here]:(http://tinypic.com/r/wh1v8p/6)

is a snapshot of cpu threads where red color shows blocked, green runnable and yellow is waiting. I problem is that threads are running one at a time I do not know why?

Note:I know that this is not thread safe but I know that I will only be doing read operations throughout now and just want to analyse raw performance gain that can be achieved, later I will implement a better version.

Comment: What is the signature of bloomFilterInstance#contains(T)? Is it by any chance synchronized?

Comment: no it does not use synchronnized block

Comment: How many threads did you use? Show the code that launches the threads.

Comment: added the code that creates thread.

Comment: added the profiling information

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam - the idea of suggesting profiling was you get YOU to do the work of thinking / analysing why your application isn't giving much parallelism.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please tell where I have missed

One possibility is that the cost of creating threads is swamping any possible performance gains from doing the computations in parallel.  We can't really tell if this is a real possibility because you haven't included the relevant code in the question.

Another possibility is that you only have one processor / core available.  Threads only run when there is a processor to run them.  So your expectation of a linear speed with the number of threads and only *possibly* achieved (in theory) if is a free processor for each thread.

Finally, there could be memory contention due to the threads all attempting to access a shared array.  If you had proper synchronization, that would potentially add further contention.  (Note: I haven't tried to understand the algorithm to figure out if contention is likely in your example.)

---

My initial advice would be to profile your code, and see if that offers any insights.

And take a look at the way you are measuring performance to make sure that you aren't just seeing some benchmarking artefact; e.g. JVM warmup effects.

Answer (score 0):

That process looks CPU bound.  (no I/O, database calls, network calls, etc.) I can think of two explanations:

1. How many CPUs does your machine have?  How many is Java allowed to use? - if the threads are competing for the same CPU, you've added coordination work and placed more demand on the same resource.
2. How long does the whole method take to run?  For very short times, the additional work in context switching threads could overpower the actual work.  The way to deal with this is to make a longer job.  Also, run it a lot of times in a loop not counting the first few iterations (like a warm up, they aren't representative.)

Comment: I have 2 cores. Do you need to explicitly instruct jvm to use 2 cores??
The whole method took 6112 ms with threads and 5334 without multi-threading

Comment: No.  It should use both cores by default.

Comment: Can you please check the profiling which I have done.It clearly shows that no two threads ran in parallel at any time and that is why the performance decreased. Please give some reason for this I am totally confused with this behaviour

Comment: Observations: No threading at all goes on for the first two thirds of your programs execution time.  For the last third, both cores are being used.  You aren't going to see all 5 going simultaneously since you only have two cores.  Which means they have to swap out (which isn't making things faster.)  But doing back to the bulk of the time - the first twenty seconds.  What is happening there that takes so long?  Add some timing statements or the like to see which method call is taking all that time.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities come to mind:

- There is some synchronization going on inside `bloomFilterInstance`'s implementation (which is not given).
- There is a lot of memory allocation going on, e.g., what appears to be an unnecessary copy of an `ArrayList` when `chkDataSet` is created, use of `new Integer` instead of `Integer.valueOf`. You may be running into overhead costs for memory allocation.
- You may be CPU-bound (if `bloomFilterInstance#contains` is expensive) and threads are simply blocking for CPU instead of executing.

A profiler may help reveal the actual problem.